# Django Rest Framework, Query Dict is empty when using MultiPartParser

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to upload images by using DRF:

I have simple serializer:

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('file',)
```

This `file` field is simple `ImageField` in my model.

Then I have created viewset:

```
class ImagesViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    @action(methods=['post'], detail=False,
            permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])
    def upload_avatar(self, request):
        print(request.data)
        return Response({"image": "ok"})
```

I just want to print what I'm trying to upload.

After makeing request to upload data:

[image: upload2]

My Query Dict returns me:

```
<QueryDict: {}>
```

Is it bug? Or I did miss something?

Version of DRF: 3.8.2

Django: 2.0.6

Comment: @neverwalkaloner Already did this, still empty.

Comment: It may be postman bug. try to remove `Content-Type` from  request header in postman before sending request. Sometime postman doesn't set correct header(content type).that may be the problem.

Comment: It may be postman bug. try to remove `Content-Type` from  request header in postman before sending request.

Comment: @Kaushal. It worked. Strange. This is very annoying error. Please can you write it as an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: sure it will help other users also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be postman bug. try to remove `Content-Type` from request header in postman before sending request.

Sometime postman doesn't set correct header(content type).that may be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

How about django's [request.FILES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) instead of request.data?? Django Docs [File Uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#file-uploads) says

> When Django handles a file upload, the file data ends up placed in request.FILES..